# How to detect if HttpServletRequest has body?

Tags: servlets

I am trying to detect if an http request has body without reading it or doing anything that makes it impossible for the existing code to do with it whatever it does later in the flow.

```
boolean hasBody(HttpServletRequest http) {
    boolean hasBody = false;
    try {
        hasBody = http.getInputStream() != null; // always gives true
        hasBody = http.getReader().ready(); // always gives IllegalStateException
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return hasBody;
}
```

Unfortunately both checks I could come up with don't work when I test them both as GET and as POST with body.

Note, I don't want to do: `"POST".equals(http.getMethod())` or `!"GET".equals(http.getMethod())` if possible, 'cause I'm not sure what methods there could be with or without body.

Comment: Get don’t have body

Comment: true, but what about OPTION, DELETE? I'd like to know if there is or isn't without trying to guess from the getMethod()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use getContentLength() or getContentLengthLong() and check if it is positive.

Comment: I'll use: hasBody = http.getContentLength() > -1, IMHO I can send an empty post and then it will be 0

Comment: You can check if it is >0 then

Answer (score 1):

A request that includes a body should have a certain headers set if it follows https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3

> The presence of a message body in a request is signaled by a
> Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field.

You can check the presence of these headers with `http.getHeader("transfer-encoding") != null || http.getHeader("content-length") != null`.

The request body may be present but empty. If you want to catch that you could add a check for content length > 0, but that will only work if the request includes a content length header. It looks like you have to try to read the request body to see if it is empty when there is no content length header.

Comment: http.getContentLength() > -1 will be good enough. Reading is not an option since that would break the functionality of the code that reads it later in the flow.

Comment: This would work only when you have a request body of size <2GB. Because getContentLength returns an integer and 2GB makes the int value to go above MAX INT value. So that too will return -1. 

So if you are getting request bodies of size greater than 2GB, i'd recommend you use request.getContentLengthLong() to get the size since that limit will be around 9000GB. 

But the request.getContentLengthLong() only works since Servlet 3.1